# What are the possible values for maxmemory_policy in Redis?

Tags: memory, redis

In the example in the Redis [INFO](http://redis.io/commands/INFO) page, there's a `maxmemory_policy` setting:

```
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
```

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this. What are the possible values, and what is the default?

Comment: http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

Comment: No documentation, really? How did you search?

Answer (score 7):

The different eviction policies are detailed in the [`redis.conf`](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf) file:

```
# MAXMEMORY POLICY: how Redis will select what to remove when maxmemory
# is reached. You can select among five behaviors:
#
# volatile-lru -> remove the key with an expire set using an LRU algorithm
# allkeys-lru -> remove any key according to the LRU algorithm
# volatile-random -> remove a random key with an expire set
# allkeys-random -> remove a random key, any key
# volatile-ttl -> remove the key with the nearest expire time (minor TTL)
# noeviction -> don't expire at all, just return an error on write operations
#
# Note: with any of the above policies, Redis will return an error on write
#       operations, when there are no suitable keys for eviction.
#
#       At the date of writing these commands are: set setnx setex append
#       incr decr rpush lpush rpushx lpushx linsert lset rpoplpush sadd
#       sinter sinterstore sunion sunionstore sdiff sdiffstore zadd zincrby
#       zunionstore zinterstore hset hsetnx hmset hincrby incrby decrby
#       getset mset msetnx exec sort
#
# The default is:
#
# maxmemory-policy noeviction
```